# didFinishPickingImage won't perform segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, segue

I'm trying to perform a segue after I've used the UIImagePickerController, but the didFinishPickingImage function won't perform it, and I honestly have no idea why.

My code simply looks like this:

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fromidtomain", sender: self)
}
```

There's also some saving of the image involved but I'm guessing that's not relevant.

Any suggestions on how to do this properly would be appreciated.

EDIT: It works now, but only if I put the segue-code inside an if statement in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` delegate in your class.

```
class GameOver: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's already done, I have a lot of other code in my didFinishPickingImage which works, it's only the segue that doesn't. That's the name of the segue.